# How to change button color when it takes background color?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Here i gave screenshot of my screen and i want the entire button color to change when hovered but only borders or changing button takes background color in cente area how can i chage it

[image]

```
class window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PAVAI")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(/home/balaji/black.png)")
        #self.setStyleSheet('background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1,stop: 0 white, stop: 0.4 gray,stop: 1 green);')


        Calculate = QtGui.QPushButton("SHRINKAGE",self)
        Calculate.move(100,200)
        Calculate.resize(270,320)
        Calculate.setStyleSheet('QPushButton :{ background-color: red; }')
        Calculate.setStyleSheet('QPushButton:hover{ background-color: red; }')
        Calculate.clicked.connect(self.shrinkage)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a stylesheet to a widget without indicating a selector, it will be applied to the widget and its children, so when you use `background-image: url(/home/balaji/black.png)` it also applies to the buttons, so red background if you are setting it but the `background-image` is on top of it. One solution is to set a `background-image: url()` on the button when the hover state is active that will eliminate the background image set in the QMainWindow:

```
class window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PAVAI")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(/home/balaji/black.png)")
        calculate = QtGui.QPushButton("SHRINKAGE",self)
        calculate.setGeometry(100,200, 270,320)
        calculate.setStyleSheet(''' 
            QPushButton:hover{ background-color: red; background-image: url()}
        ''')
```

---

**Additional notes:**

- I see that you are calling twice `Calculate.setStyleSheet(...)`, in this case only the last one will be used.
- I recommend you read the following links about the Qt Style Sheet rules:

  - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
  - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
  - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html